# A question about ROS Laser Scan Assembler

Tags: ros, laser-scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using single scan sensor_msgs/LaserScan message provided in laser.bag, and I try to use the Laser Scan Assembler to form a bigger point cloud, by it fails in rviz (seems not bring in sensor_msgs/PointCloud message). what are the possible reasons?

links:[www.ros.org/wiki/laser_assembler/Tutorials/HowToAssembleLaserScans](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_assembler/Tutorials/HowToAssembleLaserScans)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51959/a-question-about-ros-laser-scan-assembler/) by [saddddddd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3927/saddddddd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saddddddd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3927/saddddddd/) on 2013-01-14**:
Ok, finally, I find I use a wrong simulation time, as the clock section said, we should set /use_sim_time to true before we run the service calling node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is deals with the message type. If you open it as a PointCloud2 in RVIZ, it should work.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0